# Print Status em uma unica linha

Tags: python-3.x

É possível fazer um informativo de status do script via terminal?

Por exemplo, tenho uma função chamada teste, antes dela ser executada, o script exibe no terminal:

> 'Executado teste ########## [ Loading ]'

E após o termino da execução dos passos da função, substituiria o *Loading* por 'OK' ficando:

> 'Executado teste ########## [ OK ]'

Tem como fazer isso ou algo similar a isso no Python?

Comment: Não é duplicada não. O que ele quer é saber como imprimir e alterar o texto na mesma linha.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 E é exatamente isso que é discutido na outra pergunta. Lá inclusive eu digo como contornar a limitação do `\r` quando a *string* for menor que a anterior. Talvez queira passar lá para ver.

Comment: Vish, desculpa. Eu não tinha lido direito a resposta da outra pergunta kkkk. Realmente é duplicada, peço perdão.

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim. Utilize o `\r` no início da sua string. O que esse caractere especial faz é substituir o texto a partir do início da linha atual por um novo. Exemplo:

```
import time
sprites = ["\\ ","| ","/ ","--"]
i = 0

while True:
    print("\r Loading... %s"%sprites[i],end="")
    time.sleep(0.3)
    i += 1
    if i >= len(sprites):
        i = 0
```

Como eu disse, o `"\r"` substitui o texto a partir do início por um novo, mas o restante do texto permanece o mesmo. Logo se eu executar este código aqui:

```
print("\r Como você está ?",end="")
print("\r Estou bem.",end="")
input()
```

O resultado final será:

```
Estou bem.está ?
```

Isso porque o segundo `print` não tinha caracteres o suficiente para substituir o resto do texto.

Comment: É que no caso, eu queria fazer algo assim: Funcao 1 ###### [ /' aqui seria OK ou nao OK dependendo do return do if/' ]

Comment: Acho estranho você  insistir que a questão não é duplicada, e no fim, escrever uma resposta com a mesma solução que está na resposta apontada. (você pode adicionar sua resposta lá. Você pode responder aqui só por que acredita ser mais simples. Mas clicar lá, ler a resposta, e escrever a mesma coisa de volta, acho meio over)

Comment: Vish, desculpa. Eu não tinha lido direito a resposta da outra pergunta kkkk. Realmente é duplicada, peço perdão.